'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, when using nvm
I use nvm.
even after adding path C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.19.1\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin
as we do for when using npm in env variables, ng is not recognized
I tried running
`npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`
but no use
